# Spring Not Storing Okta JSESSIONID from Auth Redirect Response

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, okta, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to secure my application with SSO. I can get user redirected to Okta's auth page, but once they authenticate with that the JSESSION Id isn't stored in spring. I get an error in the Spring logs:

```
GET "/oauth2/redirect/okta?code={code}&state={state}", parameters={masked}
Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
Resource not found
Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

So it looks like Spring is confused about the GET response being called as part of the redirect. I have my Security config set up like this:

```
public static class AuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegRepo;

        @Autowired
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth_login", "/oauth2/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegRepo)
                    .authorizedClientService(clientService);
       }
}
```

The full project can be found [here](https://github.com/WyattPearson/spring-oauth2-test).

Is there something I need to do with Spring OAuth2 to tell it to store jsessionid's into it's security context?

Comment: I don't think that's your problem - that's a 404 stating it cannot find that webpage, and you can see in the handler that there is no Request Handler for that path.

Comment: Thank you, I think that got me closer. After changing the redirect to an existing endpoint I no longer get the error in the logs. But now I just continuously get redirected to the login page. On a private window it goes login page -> okta auth -> redirect success (no page landing, I just see it in the dev console) -> login page.